# compile MongoDB C driver with vs2008 on windows7 error

Tags: mongodb

Environment  :

```
Windows 7 ,Scons 2.3.0 ,MongoDB 2.4.5(source and C++ drivers)
```

Error:

```
C:\mongo\src\mongo/platform/windows_basic.h(88) :   fatal error C1189:   
#error :  "32 bit mongo does not support Windows versions older than XP Service Pack 3"
```

I don't understand this,

thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using 32bit and not 64bit MongoDB? Also, can you clarify whether you are using the C or C++ driver?